# SMPlayer - YouTube Explorer doesn't record videos on Ubuntu 15.04.

Tags: 15.04, smplayer

On Ubuntu 14.10, SMPlayer worked properly and efficiently, but in version 15.04, this app doesn't record the videos.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution in [this article](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-smplayer-14-9-on-ubuntu-15-04-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivatives/).

Open the terminal and type the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```